# iOS AVPlayer v. MPMusicPlayerController

Tags: ios, avplayer, mpmusicplayercontroller

I am writing a music playing app which performs a task between each song. I need to do this even when the app is in the background, so I need to know when a song has completed. At the moment I am using `AVPlayer` which sends notifications even when the app is in the background, but is unable to play songs from the user's iCloud. `MPMediaPlayerController` can play iCloud songs but doesn't send notifications when the app is in the background (which is essential to my app).

So, does anyone know either

1. Any clever ways of having `AVPlayer` play iCloud songs, or
2. Having my app recognise when a song playing via `MPMusicPlayerController` has completed when the app is in the background?

Comment: Did you ever solve this for your app?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using NSNotification Center and one of these two observers? 
`MPMusicPlayerControllerPlaybackStateDidChangeNotification` or `MPMusicPlayerControllerNowPlayingItemDidChangeNotification`.

Also, you need to use `beginGeneratingPlaybackNotifications()` on your instance of `MPMusicPlayerController.applicationMusicPlayer()` or `MPMusicPlayerController.systemMusicPlayer()`

Answer (score 1):

To build on @Kim's answer. You can use the `NSNotificationCenter` and add `ObserverEvents`. I use the `MPMusicPlayerController` class for my application, and I've registered the application to use the `NSNotificationCenter` properties so I can call certain methods during differing events.

For instance, while using the `SystemMusicPlayer` property if you exit and terminate the application process, the music keeps playing. If the user wanted to stop the music when they exityou could call this:

```
-(void) registerMediaPlayerNotifications {
    NSNotificationCenter *notificationCenter = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];

    [notificationCenter addObserver:self
                           selector:@selector(stopMusicWhenApplicationQuits)
                               name:UIApplicationWillTerminateNotification
                             object:[UIApplication sharedApplication]];
    [musicPlayer beginGeneratingPlaybackNotifications];
}
```

Where you see the `@selector` that is the method that will be fired when the application receives the `UIApplicationWillTerminateNotification` event. Which in the `musicPlayer` you can say

```
[self.musicPlayer stop];
```

So for the question you have, you can still use the `MediaPlayer` framework, use the `MPMusicPlayerController` class and call various methods during different application runtime stages using the `NSNotificationCenter` properties.

Hope this helps, let me know if you have any further questions.